# I can neither upvote nor accept the answers on Mathematica SE

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am not able to upvote or accept answers to my questions on Mathematica SE. I am allegedly signed up, but have still the message "Finish signing up for your account" on the screen.

What shall I do?

Comment: @BigBadCat no it's not... well, it might be, but since the other one was "fixed", it's wrong to close this one as dupe. Those should be handled case-by-case, so we should let SE staff handle it.

Comment: Now I have used  "Contact Us" link. Let's see if it helps.

Comment: Did you validate your email address?

Comment: @Monica Cellio I do not remember this. Most probably I had already an account on math SE before I started using Mathematica SE. And the latter is the only SE page which does not recognize my signing up.

Comment: Oh, you said *Mathematica*, not *Mathematics* (Math).  I've heard that Math has additional requirements, which I speculate might include email validation, but I don't know anything about Mathematica.  Sorry!  However, your Mathematica account shows as unregistered, unlike your Math one, so maybe you used a different credential or email address?

Answer (score 1):

Your account on Mathematica is unregistered, which means you [can ask and answer but cannot vote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-register).  I thought this included not being able to accept answers, but [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307383/i-can-neither-upvote-nor-accept-the-answers-on-mathematica-se/307403?noredirect=1#comment999751_307403) provides some counter-examples.  So I don't know why you can't accept an answer, but this is why you can't upvote.

You do have a registered account on Math, though, so I would have expected your account to be registered automatically on new sites.  It might not be if you used a different credential -- for example, if you logged in with Facebook on one site and Google on another.  I *think* that if you used the same email address they're still all hooked up together in your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/8302715/drer?tab=accounts).

On your profile page on Mathematica, look for a link that says something like "register".  If it's not on the main page, look in "edit settings".  (Sorry, I don't remember exactly where it is and haven't created a new account to test with.)

Comment: hold on... unregistered accounts can't accept answers?

Comment: @Cai I thought they couldn't.  Do you know of an example?  (I know that unregistered users who came over from SE 1.0 can have acceptances, but I don't think new, unregistered users can.)

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to search for unregistered users for a min there....
 [user87505](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/87505/user87505?tab=profile) and [user105472](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/105472/user105472?tab=profile)

Comment: @Cai thanks!  I'll edit.

Comment: You were right. I indeed is able to accept answers. I have no idea what I did wrong so that this did not work.

Comment: @drer oh good; that's more consistent with what we know about unregistered accounts.  (If this answer helped you, you know what to do. :-) )

Comment: @Monica Cellio Actually I did not know what to do. :( But somebody has helped me. Obviously I had two accounts, and now they were merged together. Thus the advice to use the link "Contact Us" seems to be correct.